# Javascript: Find maximum value of object property in array in object in array :D

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the following array of objects and I want to find the highest weight of any person in any year (the weight is enough, I don't need the corresponding year or name).

Thanks in advance :)

```
var arr = [
    {
        'name': 'Bob',
        'weights': [
            {
                'weight': 90,
                'year': 2018
            },
            {
                'weight': 85,
                'year': 2017
            },
            // etc.
        ]
    },
        'name': 'Charlie',
        'weights': [
            {
                'weight': 65,
                'year': 2018
            },
            {
                'weight': 60,
                'year': 2017
            },
            // etc.
        ]
    },
    // etc.
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Math.max` and spread syntax to find max value but you also need to use `map` to get weight values in one array first.

```js
var arr = [{"name":"Bob","weights":[{"weight":90,"year":2018},{"weight":85,"year":2017}]},{"name":"Charlie","weights":[{"weight":65,"year":2018},{"weight":60,"year":2017}]}]

var max = Math.max(...[].concat(...arr.map(({weights}) => weights.map(({weight}) => weight))))
console.log(max)
```